# Manipulating input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the value in `input` using `JavaScript`. What I'm trying to achieve is, draw circles on mouse click using `JavaScript` and get whatever text there is in `input` trim the first character and place the trimmed character within the circle. I have manage to draw the circles but can't seem to figure out how to put the trimmed character inside the circle and remove it from the `input` value.

My code is:

```
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var inputText = document.getElementById("textValue").value;
    //Remove first character from the string
    inputText = inputText.slice(1);
    function createImageOnCanvas(imageId) {
        canvas.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("images").style.overflowY = "hidden";
        var img = new Image(500, 500);
        img.src = document.getElementById(imageId).src;
        context.drawImage(img, (0), (0)); 
    }

    function draw(e) {
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
        posx = pos.x;
        posy = pos.y;
        context.font = "10px Georgia";
        context.fillStyle = "#000";
        context.fillText(inputText, posx, posy); //This does not write the text to the circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(posx, posy, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.fill();
    }

    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
            y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
    }

    window.draw = draw;
</script>
```

Markup is:

```
<div id="images"></div>
<canvas style="margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;left:50px;top:50px;" id="imgCanvas" width="500" height="500" onclick="draw(event)"></canvas>
<input id="textValue" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calculating `inputText` *once*, at the start of the page, when there is nothing in there. You are then never asking for it again.

Move the `inputText = ...` logic *inside* the draw function. You will also need to assign the remaining text back to the input's value.

Comment: I've moved my logic in the draw function and it works as expected but the text is still not going onto the circle :/

Comment: I've got the circle bit working too, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just need to pass the variable back to the input value:

```
document.getElementById("textValue").value = str.slice(1,document.getElementById("textValue").value.length);
```